# Does posting a Runnable with a Handler make things asynchronous?

Tags: android, user-interface, asynchronous

I am updating an activity's UI from a BroadcastReceiver that I register in the same activity. The API docs say:

> [...] The function [onReceive()] is normally called within the main thread
>   of its process [...]

so I suppose updating the UI is okay.

The docs also say:

> [...] you should never perform long-running operations in it (there is
>   a timeout of 10 seconds [...]

I am just setting some text on a TextView so I suppose that won't ever take longer than 10 seconds.

But, and here comes finally my actual question: Does it make any sense at all to add a Runnable to the main thread's message queue using a Handler, so that onReceive() can return immediately and the UI update happens at some later point in time, as the docs suggest:

> There are two main uses for a Handler: (1) to schedule messages and
>   runnables to be executed as some point in the future; [...]

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just setting text on `TextView`s then you won't have issues. No need to over-complicate things with `Handler`s.

Though I will say that some people like using handlers just because it keeps things organized if multiple calls to a specific UI method need to be called. Using a handler will guarantee that that executed code will be initially placed on the UI thread, so it avoids having to check which thread you are running on.

The important thing to keep in mind is that all UI actions should be performed on the UI thread, and any sort of intensive processing should be done on a background thread.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using a `Handler` to schedule a `Runnable` is the standard.